# Laravel , seeder para rellenar datos "fake"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-4

Tengo este seeder con este nombre UserProfilesSeeder.php

El contenido es este

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UserProfilesSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker::create();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {

        \DB::table('users')->insert(array(
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'password' => '1234'
        ));


        \DB::table('user_profiles')->insert(array(
            'user_id' => $i,
        ));
    }
}
```

}

El archivo desde donde se llama el seeder **DatabaseSeeder.php** tiene esta estructura

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call('UserProfilesSeeder');

}
```

}

El error que me da es que no encuentra la clase "UserProfilesSeeder"

> php artisan db:seed
>
> Seeding: UserProfilesSeeder
>
> ReflectionException  : Class UserProfilesSeeder does not exist
>
> at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:794
>       790|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
>       791|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
>       792|         }
>       793|
>       794|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
>       795|
>       796|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
>       797|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
>       798|         // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente esto ocurre porque Composer no puede detectar el seeder que recién fue creado. La forma típica de solucionarlo es ejecutando el siguiente comando que actualiza las clases en los archivos compilados:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , era eso. Ya funciona